# How to concisely express the C++20 concept of range containing T-typed values?

Tags: c++, c++20

I want to write a function template that accepts ranges of `MyType`-typed values, so I wrote

```cpp
void f(const std::ranges::range auto& my_range) { /* ... */ }
```

Unfortunately this does not constrain the type of the values contained in the range. I could use a `requires` clause before the function body block but I want something reusable and not specific to this function.

Naturally I wrote

```cpp
template <class T, class V>
concept range_of = std::ranges::range<T> && std::is_same_v<V, std::ranges::range_value_t<T>>;

void f(const range_of<MyType> auto& my_range) { /* ... */ }
```

but I'm very surprised that this is not supported out-of-the-box by the standard library given how natural it seems. This also applies to `std::ranges::view` for which I could write a similar `view_of` concept.

Is my definition of `range_of` incomplete or wrong? Or is there a good reason this isn't offered by the standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is: what is the actual constraint that you want?

Do you want to:

- constrain on the range's value type being specifically `T`?
- constrain on the range's value type being convertible to `T`?
- constrain on the range's value type satisfying some other concept, `C`?
- any of the above but instead about the range's reference type?

Different contexts call for different versions of this. Your `range_of` concept is a perfectly fine implementation of the first one of these (could use `std::same_as` instead of `std::is_same_v` but doesn't super matter). But what happens when you want something else? The specific choice of constraint is going to depend very much on what it is you want to do.

So the direct answer is: there's no `range_of` concept because there's really no one true answer of what that concept should do.

---

A different answer would be that this isn't even what would be useful. What would be useful would be a direct way to pull out the associated types of a given `range` to make it easy to add further constraints on them.

For instance, if we take Rust, we can define a function that takes an arbitrary iterator:

```rust
fn foo<I: Iterator>(it: I) { ... }
```

That's sort of akin to just `void f(range auto)`. It's a constraint, but not a very useful one. But `Iterator`, in Rust, has an associated type: its `Item`. So if you wanted an `Iterator` over a specific type, that's:

```rust
fn foo<I: Iterator<Item=i32>>(it: I) { ... }
```

If you wanted an `Iterator` whose type satisfies some other constraint:

```rust
fn foo<T: Debug, I: Iterator<Item=T>>(it: I) { ... }
```

And it's really *this* ability - to pull out associated types and constrain on them directly - that we really lack.

Comment: I wonder if one could `requires( range_of< element_rewuirement, args... > )`?  I think so; `template<class R, template<class...>class EZ, class...Ts> struct range_of_impl:constant<EZ< deref_type<R>, Ts... >::value>{};`?  I thonk that would work.  Then `requires( range_of< is_same, BobType > )`, `requires( range_of< is_convertable, BobType >)` (hmm, order wrong there).

Comment: @Barry Thanks for your answer, you are right on all points. I think it is better to inspect the `range_reference_t` rather than the `range_value_t` because it's what we get out of iterating over the range whereas the `value_type` is less useful. Secondly, with `range_of` I wanted to express the notion that the value type is `V`-like "enough" but I hadn't realized there may be several interpretations of what "enough" means.

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I have tried that and it worked (more easily with `std::is_convertible` than with `std::is_same` too). But it's quite complex for application code.